# Jest v28 sharding, merge coverage report to single file missing branch data

Tags: jestjs, lcov

Using Jest v28 `--shard` flag significantly speeds up tests in our CI/CD pipeline, but it creates the issue of having to merge multiple coverage reports into a single file (required for our code quality report on PRs).

I am forced to use `lcov` format for the coverage report. I am able to merge the coverage report using `lcov` CLI tool:

```
lcov --add-tracefile ./coverage-unit/lcov-1.info --add-tracefile ./coverage-unit/lcov-2.info  --output-file ./coverage-unit/lcov.info
```

But the merged `./coverage-unit/lcov.info` file does not pick up the branch data:

```
Combining tracefiles.
Reading tracefile ./coverage-unit/lcov-1.info
Reading tracefile ./coverage-unit/lcov-2.info
Writing data to ./coverage-unit/lcov.info
Summary coverage rate:
  lines......: 87.9% (5003 of 5691 lines)
  functions..: 85.4% (543 of 636 functions)
  branches...: no data found
```

This results in a merged `lcov.info` that is omitting the `BRH`, `BRF`, and `BRDA` fields.

Is there a proper way to merge `lcov` report files?

Answer (score 0):

`lcov` has [branch coverage data disabled by default](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcovrc.5.php). Using the `lcov_branch_coverage=1` flag enables it.

The following command properly merges the coverage reports with branch coverage data:

```
lcov --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 \
  --add-tracefile ./coverage-unit/lcov-1.info \
  --add-tracefile ./coverage-unit/lcov-2.info  \
  --output-file ./coverage-unit/lcov.info
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer shows a different solution, instead of working with `lcov` report files. This is justified as it is easy to produce different output by just adding a different coverage reporter to the jest configuration.

I was able to merge the coverage reports of my shards by copying them all together in a directory called `.nyc_output` [1]. To be precise, you need the `json` coverage reporter and you need to copy the `coverage-final.json` files (they're named exactly like this) to the `.nyc_output` directory (renaming them, e.g. by adding the shard number to the file name). Contrary to the linked reference, you don't need a single `out.json` file. Any number of json files (with arbitrary names) will be picked up when generating the report.

For example:

```
$ ls .nyc_output
coverage-shard-1.json  coverage-shard-2.json  coverage-shard-3.json
```

From there (to be precise, from a parent folder relative to `.nyc_output`), you can just run `npx nyc report --reporter=html` (you might want to add a version number to the `nyc` package, i.e. at the time of writing this, `nyc@latest` equals `nyc@15`). This will generate the HTML coverage report and save it to the `coverage` directory.

If you're not interested in an HTML report it might work by specifying other reporters in the `--reporter` argument (I did not test this). You can alternatively merge all the json files together into a single json file like this [2]:

`npx nyc merge .nyc_output your-merged-coverage.json`

References:

1. https://istanbul.js.org/docs/advanced/coverage-object-report/
2. https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#what-about-nyc-merge